# UIButton with custom font and text outline/stroke

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I've got a huge problem, I need to make a UIButton with custom font and text outline. Custom font is pretty easy to make and I have no difficulties doing it, but I don't know how to make an outline for button title. There are some solutions for UILabel (overriding drawTextInRect) but UIButton has no such method. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just put the customized UILabel on top of a blank button.

Comment: I was hoping for something more ... elegant?)